# React Native use_native_modules documentation

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I can't any documentation regarding `use_native_modules` in Podfile. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

`use_native_modules` is a function defined and called by [react-native/cli](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/packages/platform-ios/native_modules.rb) for [autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/3.x/docs/autolinking.md) purposes.

Here is the original pull request for this feature: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/256

Here is it's description from source code:

```
# This is a function which is used inside your Podfile.
# It uses `react-native config` to grab a list of dependencies, and pulls out.all of the ones
# which declare themselves to be iOS dependencies (via having a Podspec) and automatically
# imports those into your current target.
```